# POST to database an array variable with foreach

Tags: php, mysql

**CASE 1**

i have following code like this ,

```
<SELECT name="country[]">
<OPTION >India</OPTION>
<OPTION >Germany</OPTION>
<OPTION >France</OPTION>
<OPTION >United States</OPTION>
<OPTION >Switzerland</OPTION>
```

```
    $country = $_POST['country'];

foreach($country as $a => $b) {

$simpan = mysql_query("insert into tablename(countryyyy) values('$country[$a]')");

 }
```

why only data from first array who entered into database ?
the rest not entered into database ?

**CASE 2**

```
<INPUT type="text" name="txt[]">

<SELECT name="country[]">
    <OPTION >India</OPTION>
    <OPTION >Germany</OPTION>
    <OPTION >France</OPTION>
    <OPTION >United States</OPTION>
    <OPTION >Switzerland</OPTION>
</SELECT>  


$txtbox = $_POST['txt'];
$country = $_POST['country'];

foreach($country as $a => $b) {
$satuin =  $txtbox[$a].$country[$a]."<br/>";
$simpan = mysql_query("insert into namatabel(negara) values('$satuin')");

 }
```

if i have 2 array variable like above , how to concat all into one and post to database with  as separator
data example who want to post to one of column :
india
india
germany
india

thanks in advance

Comment: You only have one input named `country[]`, so you are only selecting one county.

Comment: I'm not getting the second question at all

Comment: i'm following this tutorial for dynamic add form --> viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/ <-- but i have problem with insert to database

Comment: Can you post the schema of `namatabel`, the database table

Comment: namatabel just have 2 column with name 'nama' and 'negara' without primary/foreign key , this table just for testing insert , have i get wrong in my database schema ?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say without seeing the schema and the kind of errors generated when you run the code. What kind of errors did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do, but if you're using select box for multiple values then you need `multiple="multiple"`  in select box something like this

```
<SELECT name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: i just following tutorial from this site : viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/ , but i have problem with post